# Reverting to the AWS Lambda execution role after assuming a role in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a Lambda function that successfully assumes a role in another account to download the WAF hits from its API.

I also need to get an SSM Param from the account where the Lambda is executed.  Of course I can just do that step first, and then later assume the role.

But I am wondering if there's a way to revert to the execution role of the Lambda itself.  In case there's some chaining that might happen in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not actually "swap" to a different role.

Rather, in your code, you specify which credentials to use.

When assuming a role, you would use:

```
import boto3

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

response = sts_client.assume_role(...)

assumed_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

You can then use that `Session` to connect to a service:

```
# Connect to WAF using assumed_session
waf_client = assumed_session.client('waf')

response = waf_client.get_sampled_requests(...)
```

When you later want to use the *default* credentials provided to the Lambda function, simply use the normal syntax:

```
# Note: No 'Session' here, just the normal way to connect
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

response = client.get_parameter(...)
```

So, don't think of being "logged-in" to a particular set of credentials. Rather, when a call is made to a service, provide a `client` that has been created using the desired set of credentials. You can then 'swap' between them as much as you like, because all that matters is the client used for each call.